# Order mail is not sending to admin in Opencart

Tags: php, email, opencart2.x

I am using **Opencart Version 2.0.3.1.**

While a customer order a product, the order mail is not sent to admin. But the order mail is successfully sent to the customer.

**So how to make  to sent the order mail to admin while an user order a product in Opencart??**

My `Mail` settings is look like this:

[image]

Other mails like contact us etc are working fine..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, solve the problem..

My issue is **the order mail is not sent to admin but sent to customer**. I have to sent the order mail to admin also.

Solution:

Login as admin, goto `System->Settings`, `Edit` the current `store`.
Move to `Option` tab, in `checkout` section `check` **New Order Alert Mail** to `Yes` and `Save`.